# Bootstrap3 navbar-fixed-top height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm using bootstrap3 with navbar-fixed-top in my project. In mentioned navbar, there is a DIV which height is about 700px and this makes entire navbar stretch for this 700px and covers my content (I'm not able to click inside inputs of main container).

Can somebody help to set the overflow parameter properly, so my element inside navbar doesn't stretch entire navbar, however stays "outside" of it?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
 ...
 <my-custom-widget></my-custom-widget> <!-- this is the widget with height of 700px -->
 ...
</nav>
```

Thanks.

G.

Comment: Please post the rest of the code so we can have a visual to work with. This does nothing for us. Setup a js fiddle or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are creating any custom widget then you can set that widget's position attribute to absolute or fixed and if you want to prevent it from oversized then you can use overflow property of css

checkout this pen for example

```
my-custom-widget{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XaezNr

Comment: Thank you. I will go with absolute position - that will be the easiest way. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a fixed height of the navbar and then set overflow to hidden. It should solve your problem. But if you have drop-down menu in that navbar then you can't see the sub-menu items anymore because of hidden overflow